# Corrupt display observed via VNC with TrueOS on QEMU

Tags: qemu, trueos

I am trying to run TrueOS v17.12x64 on QEMU but got corrupted display immediately after booting to GUI:

[image]

I am just going with the ordinary graphics setup. Here's my domain file:

```
<graphics type='vnc' port='5933' autoport='no' listen='192.168.1.56'>
  <listen type='address' address='192.168.1.56'/>
</graphics>
<video>
  <model type='cirrus' vram='16384' heads='1' primary='yes'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
</video>
```

Here's my QEMU version:

```
# qemu-system-i386 --version
QEMU emulator version 2.8.1(Debian 1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u3)
Copyright (c) 2003-2016 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers
```

Looks like QEMU is not officially supported as a target platform according to [here](https://www.trueos.org/handbook/install.html) but I am wondering if anyone ran into this before and managed to work it out?